# Entity Framework data not saved to database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, mdf

I'm making an application using C# and Entity Framework 6. The data is not saved to the database for some reason.

I have tried doing things that were suggested for similar problems here at stackoverflow and other forums:
 - Changing entry state to modified.
- Setting "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy if newer".
- Placing the code in other project, making it simpler trying to narrow
   down the problem.
- Comparing to projects I did in the past, seeing what have I done differently this time.

None of these helped so I am pretty much screwed here :D

SQL for creating the database (the part of it when creating those tables I'm using in the functions that doesn't work)

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Username varchar(64),
  Name varchar(64),
  Password binary(255),
  PasswordSalt binary(255),
  Validity int,
  IdentificationServer int,
  AuditDate datetime,
  AuditUser int
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Server]
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(255),
  Type int,
  Validity int,
  AuditDate datetime,
  AuditUser int
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD FOREIGN KEY (AuditUser) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] (ID);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Server] ADD FOREIGN KEY (AuditUser) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] (ID);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdentificationServer) REFERENCES [dbo].[Server] (ID);
```

Trying to add a new user to the database:

```cs
private void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = -1;
    if(m_DBManager.AttemptLogin(textBox_username.Text, textBox_password.Text, out id))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login successful! UserID: " + id);
    }
}
```

AttemptLogin:

```
public bool AttemptLogin(string username, string password, out int userID)
{
    userID = -1;
    List<User> users = GetUsers();
    foreach (User user in m_DBEntities.User)
    {
        if (username == user.Username && PasswordEncription.VerifyPassword(password, user.PasswordSalt, user.Password))
        {
            userID = user.ID;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Just to add a default user if the database is empty - this is what's not working.
    // I will delete this afterwards, but here is when I realized that my data is not saved.
    if (m_DBEntities.User.Count() == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty");
        byte[] passwordSalt = PasswordEncription.GenerateSalt();
        byte[] passwordHashed = PasswordEncription.ComputeHash(password, passwordSalt);
        AddUser("Maul Ádám", username, passwordHashed, passwordSalt, (int)ValidityStates.ENABLED, -1, -1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

AddUser:

```cs
public void AddUser(string name, string username, byte[] password, byte[] passwordSalt, int validity, int identificationServer, int userID)
{
    User user = new User();
    user.Name = name;
    user.Username = username;
    user.Password = password;
    user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
    user.Validity = validity;
    if (identificationServer != -1)
    {
        user.IdentificationServer = identificationServer;
    }
    if(userID != -1)
    {
        user.AuditUser = userID;
    }
    user.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
    m_DBEntities.User.Add(user);
    m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
    //Log((int)LogTypes.Add, "User added - ID: " + user.ID, userID);
}
```

EDIT:
Entity objects
Server:

```cs
public partial class Server
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Server()
    {
       this.User1 = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Validity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AuditDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AuditUser { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> User1 { get; set; }
}
```

User:

```cs
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.Log = new HashSet<Log>();
        this.Module = new HashSet<Module>();
        this.Parameter = new HashSet<Parameter>();
        this.Server = new HashSet<Server>();
        this.UIElement_Property = new HashSet<UIElement_Property>();
        this.User1 = new HashSet<User>();
        this.User_group_pair = new HashSet<User_group_pair>();
        this.Usergroup = new HashSet<Usergroup>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Validity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdentificationServer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AuditDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AuditUser { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Log { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Module { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Server> Server { get; set; }
    public virtual Server Server1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UIElement_Property> UIElement_Property { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> User1 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<User_group_pair> User_group_pair { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Usergroup> Usergroup { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit: DBManager class**

```cs
namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        private FrameworkDBEntities m_DBEntities;

        public DBManager()
        {
            m_DBEntities = new FrameworkDBEntities();
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public List<Module> GetModulesWithGroup(int groupID)
        {
            return (from gmp in m_DBEntities.Group_module_pair
                    where gmp.UsergroupID == groupID
                    select gmp.Module).ToList();
        }

        public List<Usergroup> GetGroupsWithModule(int moduleID)
        {
            return (from gmp in m_DBEntities.Group_module_pair
                    where gmp.ModuleID == moduleID
                    select gmp.Usergroup).ToList();
        }

        public List<Group_module_pair> GetModulePairsWithGroup(int groupID)
        {
            return (from gmp in m_DBEntities.Group_module_pair
                    where gmp.UsergroupID == groupID
                    select gmp).ToList();
        }

        public List<Group_module_pair> GetModulePairsWithModule(int moduleID)
        {
            return (from gmp in m_DBEntities.Group_module_pair
                    where gmp.ModuleID == moduleID
                    select gmp).ToList();
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public List<Log> GetLogs(int logType)
        {
            return (from l in m_DBEntities.Log
                    where l.Type == logType
                    select l).ToList();
        }

        public List<Log> GetLogs(int logType, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
        {
            return (from l in m_DBEntities.Log
                    where
                        l.Type == logType &&
                        l.AuditDate >= dateFrom && 
                        l.AuditDate <= dateTo
                    select l).ToList();
        }

        public void Log(int logType, string message, int userID)
        {
            Log newLog = new Log();
            newLog.Type = logType;
            newLog.Message = message;
            newLog.AuditUser = userID;
            newLog.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.Log.Add(newLog);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
        }

        public bool RemoveLog(int id)
        {
            Log log = m_DBEntities.Log.SingleOrDefault(l => l.ID == id);
            if (log == null) return false;
            m_DBEntities.Log.Remove(log);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        public void ClearLog()
        {
            var query = from l in m_DBEntities.Log
                        select l;

            foreach(var l in query)
            {
                m_DBEntities.Log.Remove(l);
            }
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public bool GetModule(int id, out Module module)
        {
            module = m_DBEntities.Module.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
            return module == null ? false : true;
        }

        public void AddModule(string name, int validity, int userID)
        {
            Module module = new Module();
            module.Name = name;
            module.Validity = validity;
            module.AuditUser = userID;
            module.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.Module.Add(module);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Add, "Modul hozzáadva - ID: " + module.ID, userID);
        }

        public bool ModifyModule(int id, string name, int validity, int userID)
        {
            Module module = m_DBEntities.Module.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
            if (module == null) return false;
            module.Name = name;
            module.Validity = validity;
            module.AuditUser = userID;
            module.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Modify, "Modul szerkesztve - ID: " + module.ID, userID);
            return true;
        }

        public bool RemoveModule(int id, int userID)
        {
            Module module = m_DBEntities.Module.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
            if (module == null) return false;

            List<Group_module_pair> pairsWithModule = GetModulePairsWithModule(module.ID);
            foreach(Group_module_pair gmp in pairsWithModule)
            {
                m_DBEntities.Group_module_pair.Remove(gmp);
            }

            Log((int)LogTypes.Remove, "Modul törölve - ID: " + module.ID, userID);
            m_DBEntities.Module.Remove(module);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public bool GetParameter(int id, out Parameter systemconfig)
        {
            systemconfig = m_DBEntities.Parameter.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
            return systemconfig == null ? false : true;
        }

        public void AddParameter(string name, string value, int userID)
        {
            Parameter systemconfig = new Parameter();
            systemconfig.Name = name;
            systemconfig.Value = value;
            systemconfig.AuditUser = userID;
            systemconfig.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.Parameter.Add(systemconfig);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Add, "Paraméter hozzáadva - ID: " + systemconfig.ID, userID);
        }

        public bool ModifyParameter(int id, string name, string value, int userID)
        {
            Parameter parameter = m_DBEntities.Parameter.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
            if (parameter == null) return false;
            parameter.Name = name;
            parameter.Value = value;
            parameter.AuditUser = userID;
            parameter.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Modify, "Paraméter módosítva - ID: " + parameter.ID, userID);
            return true;
        }

        public bool RemoveParameter(int id, int userID)
        {
            Parameter parameter = m_DBEntities.Parameter.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
            if (parameter == null) return false;
            Log((int)LogTypes.Remove, "Paraméter törölve - ID: " + parameter.ID, userID);
            m_DBEntities.Parameter.Remove(parameter);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public bool GetServer(int id, out Server server)
        {
            server = m_DBEntities.Server.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
            return server == null ? false : true;
        }

        public void AddServer(string name, int type, int validity, int userID)
        {
            Server server = new Server();
            server.Name = name;
            server.Type = type;
            server.Validity = validity;
            server.AuditUser = userID;
            server.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.Server.Add(server);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Add, "Szerver hozzáadva - ID: " + server.ID, userID);
        }

        public bool ModifyServer(int id, string name, int type, int validity, int userID)
        {
            Server server = m_DBEntities.Server.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
            if (server == null) return false;
            server.Name = name;
            server.Type = type;
            server.Validity = validity;
            server.AuditUser = userID;
            server.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Modify, "Szerver módosítva - ID: " + server.ID, userID);
            return true;   
        }

        public bool RemoveServer(int id, int userID)
        {
            Server server = m_DBEntities.Server.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
            if (server == null) return false;
            Log((int)LogTypes.Remove, "Szerver törölve - ID: " + server.ID, userID);
            m_DBEntities.Server.Remove(server);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public bool GetUser(int id, out User user)
        {
            user = m_DBEntities.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            return user == null ? false : true;
        }

        public List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return (from u in m_DBEntities.User select u).ToList();
        }

        public void AddUser(string name, string username, byte[] password, byte[] passwordSalt, int validity, int identificationServer, int userID)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Name = name;
            user.Username = username;
            user.Password = password;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
            user.Validity = validity;
            if (identificationServer != -1)
            {
                user.IdentificationServer = identificationServer;
            }
            if(userID != -1)
            {
                user.AuditUser = userID;
            }
            user.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.User.Add(user);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            //Log((int)LogTypes.Add, "User added - ID: " + user.ID, userID);
        }

        public bool ModifyUser(int id, string name, byte[] password, byte[] passwordSalt, int validity, int identificationServer, int userID)
        {
            User user = m_DBEntities.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            if (user == null) return false;
            user.Name = name;
            user.Password = password;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
            user.Validity = validity;
            user.IdentificationServer = identificationServer;
            user.AuditUser = userID;
            user.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            //Log((int)LogTypes.Modify, "Felhasználó szerkesztve - ID: " + user.ID, userID);
            return true;
        }

        public bool RemoveUser(int id, int userID)
        {
            User user = m_DBEntities.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            if (user == null) return false;

            List<User_group_pair> pairsWithUser = GetUserPairsWithUser(user.ID);
            foreach (User_group_pair ugp in pairsWithUser)
            {
                m_DBEntities.User_group_pair.Remove(ugp);
            }

            //Log((int)LogTypes.Remove, "Felhasználó törölve - ID: " + user.ID, userID);
            m_DBEntities.User.Remove(user);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        public bool AttemptLogin(string username, string password, out int userID)
        {
            userID = -1;
            List<User> users = GetUsers();
            foreach (User user in m_DBEntities.User)
            {
                if (username == user.Username && PasswordEncription.VerifyPassword(password, user.PasswordSalt, user.Password))
                {
                    userID = user.ID;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // Just to add a default user if the database is empty - this is what's not working.
            // I will delete this afterwards, but here is when I realized that my data is not saved.
            if (m_DBEntities.User.Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empty");
                byte[] passwordSalt = PasswordEncription.GenerateSalt();
                byte[] passwordHashed = PasswordEncription.ComputeHash(password, passwordSalt);
                AddUser("Maul Ádám", username, passwordHashed, passwordSalt, (int)ValidityStates.ENABLED, -1, -1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public bool GetUsergroup(int id, out Usergroup usergroup)
        {
            usergroup = m_DBEntities.Usergroup.SingleOrDefault(ugp => ugp.ID == id);
            return usergroup == null ? false : true;
        }

        public void AddUsergroup(string name, int validity, int userID)
        {
            Usergroup usergroup = new Usergroup();
            usergroup.Name = name;
            usergroup.Validity = validity;
            usergroup.AuditUser = userID;
            usergroup.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.Usergroup.Add(usergroup);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Add, "Felhasználói csoport hozzáadva - ID: " + usergroup.ID, userID);
        }

        public bool ModifyUsergroup(int id, string name, int validity, int userID)
        {
            Usergroup usergroup = m_DBEntities.Usergroup.SingleOrDefault(ugp => ugp.ID == id);
            if (usergroup == null) return false;
            usergroup.Name = name;
            usergroup.Validity = validity;
            usergroup.AuditUser = userID;
            usergroup.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            Log((int)LogTypes.Modify, "Felhasználói csoport szerkesztve - ID: " + usergroup.ID, userID);
            return true;
        }

        public bool RemoveUsergroup(int id, int userID)
        {
            Usergroup usergroup = m_DBEntities.Usergroup.SingleOrDefault(ugp => ugp.ID == id);
            if (usergroup == null) return false;

            List<User_group_pair> userPairsWithGroup = GetUserPairsWithGroup(usergroup.ID);
            foreach (User_group_pair ugp in userPairsWithGroup)
            {
                m_DBEntities.User_group_pair.Remove(ugp);
            }

            List<Group_module_pair> modulePairsWithGroup = GetModulePairsWithGroup(usergroup.ID);
            foreach (Group_module_pair gmp in modulePairsWithGroup)
            {
                m_DBEntities.Group_module_pair.Remove(gmp);
            }

            Log((int)LogTypes.Remove, "Felhasználói csoport törölve - ID: " + usergroup.ID, userID);
            m_DBEntities.Usergroup.Remove(usergroup);
            m_DBEntities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
}

namespace Controller.DBManagement
{
    public partial class DBManager
    {
        public List<User> GetUsersWithGroup(int groupID)
        {
            return (from ugp in m_DBEntities.User_group_pair
                    where ugp.GroupID == groupID
                    select ugp.User).ToList();
        }

        public List<Usergroup> GetGroupsWithUser(int userID)
        {
            return (from ugp in m_DBEntities.User_group_pair
                    where ugp.UserID == userID
                    select ugp.Usergroup).ToList();
        }

        public List<User_group_pair> GetUserPairsWithGroup(int groupID)
        {
            return (from ugp in m_DBEntities.User_group_pair
                    where ugp.GroupID == groupID
                    select ugp).ToList();
        }

        public List<User_group_pair> GetUserPairsWithUser(int userID)
        {
            return (from ugp in m_DBEntities.User_group_pair
                    where ugp.UserID == userID
                    select ugp).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

When restarting the program, the check for empty returns true, and the record is added locally, but it disappears with every run.

Comment: What do your entity objects for User and Server look like? Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: Added the Server and User classes above. No errors thrown, the data is just not saved.

Comment: What's this `m_DBManager` lookin like?

Comment: Its just creating the DBEntities object, stored in a private variable, and the DBManager class contains the functions AddUser and AttemptLogin.
`private FrameworkDBEntities m_DBEntities;public DBManager()  
{  
    m_DBEntities = new FrameworkDBEntities();  
}`

Comment: Is it possible to see that class as well? SaveChanges isn't throwing any form of error which it would if something wasn't configured properly. The fact it's running smooth but not persisting makes me think the context simply isn't tracking the addition of your user. That setup is happening within your `m_DBManager` class, which is unknown at this point.

Comment: I added the DBManager class but its made up of like 8-9 partial classes so its pretty long..

Comment: It's unlikely that the data is not stored in the database, so I don't think all that code matters. You can easily check that by activating EF command log and see if EF issues `INSERT` command. If the data disappears *after restart*, then you probably are using local project *mdf* file which replaces the one which is attached and used during the application lifetime.

Comment: Visual Studio even asks if i want to copy the mdf file to the project, because its not a part of it, so i click yes, and its copied to the project directory. Other than that i cant find any properties i haven't tried to change to solve the problem..
Checking that out now, thank you.

Comment: It seems like it does the insert, but i don't really know what to do about the file then.

Comment: May be try using m_DBEntities.SubmitChanges() instead of SaveChanges().. In your foreach inside AttemptLogin shouldn’t you loop through a list of “users” which you’ve obtained from GetUsers() function..

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work somehow, by deleting the parts of password hashing, I am not sure what happened there, but now it works..